# formating simplexml object is wrong

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to format from a simpleXML object, but its returning:

```
title1title2title3<a href=""></a>
```

Even though this is...

```
 return '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

Here's my whole code.

```
<?php 

class ForumFeed {
    private function getXMLFeeds($feed = 'all')
    {
        /*
            Fetch the XML feeds
         */
        $globalFeedXML = file_get_contents('/forum/syndication.php?limit=3');
        $newsFeedXML = file_get_contents('/forum/syndication.php?fid=4&limit=3');

        /*
            Turn feed objects
         */
        $globalFeed = new SimpleXMLElement($globalFeedXML);
        $newsFeed = new SimpleXMLElement($newsFeedXML);

        /*
            Return requested feed
         */
        if ($feed == 'news') {
            return $newsFeed;
        } else if ($feed == 'all') {
            return $globalFeed;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    private function formatFeeds($feed, $node)
    {
        /*
            Format Feeds for displayable content..
         */
        $getFeedObject = $this->getXMLFeeds($feed);
        $feedData = $getFeedObject->xpath('channel/item/'.$node);
        while (list( , $node) = each($feedData)) {
            echo $node;
        }
    }

    public function feed($feed)
    {
        $title = $this->formatFeeds($feed, 'title');
        $url = $this->formatFeeds($feed, 'url');
        return '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    }
}

$feeds = new ForumFeed();

echo $feeds->feed('all');
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this function:

```
private function formatFeeds($feed, $node)
{
    /*
        Format Feeds for displayable content..
     */
    $getFeedObject = $this->getXMLFeeds($feed);
    $feedData = $getFeedObject->xpath('channel/item/'.$node);
    while (list( , $node) = each($feedData)) {
        echo $node;
    }
}
```

It's echoing `$node`, rather than returning anything to the caller. Try something like this:

```
private function formatFeeds($feed, $node)
{
    /*
        Format Feeds for displayable content..
     */
    $getFeedObject = $this->getXMLFeeds($feed);
    $feedData = $getFeedObject->xpath('channel/item/'.$node);
    $result = array();
    while (list( , $node) = each($feedData)) {
        $result[] = $node;
    }
    return implode(', ', $result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! However this results in a single link wrapped around all of the titles, what should happen is a link is wrapped around each title

Comment: If you want that, you need to redesign it. Either `formatFeeds` should  return an array of titles, and you loop in `feed`. Or `formatFeeds` should wrap the link around each title, instead of it being done in `feed`.

Comment: Ah thanks, still new to OOP and trying to wrap my head around classes.

Comment: What does this have to do with classes? You'd have the same problem with an ordinary function.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working actually, but now i'm a bit clueless. I need one more node from the xml, which is $link.. Not sure how to do both $title and $link here...

Comment: Return an array of associative arrays, then loop through that, putting the link in the `href` attribute and the title in the text.